# Crappy YouTube quality with HTML5 player?

Tags: youtube, html5, linux

I have a fresh installation of Fedora 17 Beta that I've installed the relevant codecs for. VLC seems to be handling playback.

However, on all the YouTube videos with the HTML5 player the quality is really bad. Everything is blocky and pixilated. Here's an example:

[image: Freddiew]

Specs

- Fedora 17 Beta
- Fully updated Firefox 11.0
- VLC 2.0.0
- Codecs from RPM Fusion - `gstreamer-plugins-bad-free` `gstreamer-ffmpeg` `gstreamer-plugins-bad` `gstreamer-plugins-ugly`
- Settings in youtube are on "Always choose the best quality for my connection and player size"
- Still low quality when I choose "Open with VLC Media Player"

Is there anything I can do to make HTML5 playback play at an acceptable quality?

Comment: Have you tried gst-plugins-good?

Comment: @Sed Already installed, must of been as a dependency

Answer (score 0):

firefox handles html5 video natively.

go to [config page](http://youtube.com/html5) and set to use html5, yours looks more like swfviewer or so